# Одинаковые имена проекта для Netbeans и Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

Можно ли одновременно положить проект Netbaens и Eclipse в одну папку, т.е. исходники одни, а открывают их либо тем либо тем?

Comment: как вариант можно создать 3 проэкта в разных папках. а саму папку с исходниками положить еще куда-то. в каждом проэкте сделать ссылку на папку src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Файлы настроек проекта у них разные.

Comment: Сори за офтоп: интересует то же самое только для Eclipse и Intellij Idea

Comment: Ответ такой же

Answer (score 0):

а лучше всего использовать [maven](http://maven.apache.org/), тогда ни с Netbeans, ни с Eclipse, ни с Intellij Idea, ни с ещё чем-нибудь проблем не будет)

Comment: Интересно.. надо бы изучить =)

Comment: maven уже не модно, уже надо учить [gradle](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle)